# How to use an array declared in a function into another function without passing it

Tags: javascript

I have two functions.

The first one will calculate the mean of array, and it return an array of mean , maximum value and minimum value.

The second function take an array from a `td` in a table, and pass it to the `calcMean` function.
The problem I have is how to get the values mean, max, min (values which are elements in array) into that function.

Current code:

```
function calcMean(nums){
  var num = 0;

  for (var i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
    num += parseFloat(nums[i]);
  }

  var divide = num/nums.length;

  mean = (parseInt(divide,10));

  var maxi = Math.max.apply(Math,nums);
  var mini = Math.min.apply(Math,nums);

  return[mean,maxi,mini];
}

function solution(){
  var str=new Array(6);
  str=document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML;
  var arr = str.split(",");
  //alert(arr); i saw the array
  //alert(typeof arr); arr is object
  calcMean(arr);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a `return` statement!?

Comment: What's the question here?  `calcMean(arr)` returns you an array of the 3 values.  What are you stuck on?

Comment: how can i get them ,  mean , mini ,maxi,

Comment: @RocketHazmat , i really want to put the mean in an input element html ,

Comment: can  i see simply , var array = calcMean();
 arr[0] =mean ; and so so?

Answer (score 1):

You function `calcMean(arr);` called in `solution()` function return array so you can store the array in variable like following :

```
 var result = calcMean(arr);

 alert(result[0]);  //return mean value
 alert(result[1]);  //return maxi value
 alert(result[2]);  //retirn mini value
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh , thanks a lot, i think about that , but i didn't focus a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the mean of the array returned by `clacMean(arr)`:

```
var res  = calcMean(arr);
var mean = res[0];
var max  = res[1];
var min  = res[2];
```

Comment: thanks a lot , is there another way to solve this problem ?

Comment: @OraibAboRob: You could return an object.  `return {mean: mean ,maxi: maxi ,mini: mini};` then you could access it as: `var res  = calcMean(arr); var mean = res.mean;`.

Comment: Thank you very much , again :D

Answer (score -1):

You can declare mean , max and min val as global and assign value at the time of calcMean function call , then you can get this value. See below :

---

```
            var maxi=new Array();
            var mini =new Array();
            var mean;
            function calcMean(nums){
            var num=0;
            mean=0,maxi=new Array(),mini =new Array();
            for (var i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
            num += parseFloat (nums[i])}
            var divide=num/nums.length;

            mean=(parseInt(divide,10));
             maxi = Math.max.apply(Math,nums);
             mini = Math.min.apply(Math,nums);

            }

            function solution(){
            var str=new Array(6);
            str=document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML;
            var arr = str.split(",");
            calcMean(arr);
            alert(mean);
            alert(mini);
            alert(maxi);
            }
```